# How to deal with occasional alert message in selenium/Appium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, python-appium

I am doing automation and making my code dynamic, in that way either element found or not, app should run smoothly and flawlessly.
Right now, problem is there is an alert message which appears occasionally.
let us say its A.
It appears some time and some time not. Now I am using

```
A= driver.find_element_by_xpath("abc")
    if A.isdisplay():
            (whatevery my function is)
    else:
         (Do this)
```

but sometimes A does not appears, in that way script throws an exception and test got failed.
Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: how are you selecting `A`?

Comment: I am not selecting A, its pop up screen which is appearing on some places, I am storing that value in "A".

Comment: can you show the code for what you just described?

Comment: I have updated my example, check now.

Comment: Actual Code is company's property, can't disclose that.

Comment: @TeSter What is this alert? Is it some kind of random survey etc not related to currently performed action? Then it could be controlled by a cookie. Better option would be to ask the developers to set this option off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead (notice the **s**), which returns an array of found elements or an empty list if none exist. So you could use it like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("abc")

if elements and elements[0].is_displayed():
    # (whatevery your function is)
else:
    # (Do this)
```

Another way is to use a `try/catch` statement, like this for example:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    A = driver.find_element_by_xpath("abc")
except NoSuchElementException:
    A = None

if A is not None and A.is_displayed():
    # (whatevery your function is)
else:
    # (Do this)
```

Comment: The function is `is_displayed()` not `.isdisplay()`.